# Finding precision and recall for the tutorial federated learning model on MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using this tutorial to try to learn how federated models work through TensorFlow's tutorial here: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/federated/blob/master/docs/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb

Currently, the model is defined like this which uses accuracy as its metric.

```
def model_fn():
  keras_model = create_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
      keras_model,
      input_spec = preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec,
      loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy()]
  )
```

I want to either use precision and recall as metrics, or find them after the model is trained, but I can't figure out how to do so.

I tried adding precision to metrics like this `metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(), tf.keras.metrics.Precision()]` and run this code but it gives me an error.

```
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
    model_fn,
    client_optimizer_fn = lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
    server_optimizer_fn = lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.5))
```

Error output:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-f8ac3534e325> in <module>()
      2     model_fn,
      3     client_optimizer_fn = lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01),
----> 4     server_optimizer_fn = lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.5))

ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

Previously, I asked a similar question for a regular [centralized model here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729973/finding-precision-and-recall-for-mnist-dataset-using-tensorflow/67730576#67730576), but I don't think I can use that same method since you can't get the results of the predictions back in the same way from what I've found.
I've also tried looking at other documentation [such as this](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/tff_for_federated_learning_research_compression#training_the_model_and_outputting_training_metrics), but it also uses accuracy as the metric, so that wasn't helpful. How can I get the precision and recall of this federated model?

Answer (score 0):

Since **Precision** and **Recall** are naturally binary metrics, you can not use them for a multi class prediction.

The error indicates that you have 10 classes for prediction and this is incompatible with 1 class classification metric you have provided.

However, you can implement a **Custom Metric** and pass it as an argument to your `metrics`.

**1. Define a custom metric:**

```
class MulticlassTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='multiclass_true_positives', **kwargs):
        super(MulticlassTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), shape=(-1, 1))
        values = tf.cast(y_true, 'int32') == tf.cast(y_pred, 'int32')
        values = tf.cast(values, 'float32')
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, 'float32')
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.true_positives.assign(0.)
```

**2. Then pass it to your `metrics`:**

```
metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(), MulticlassTruePositives()]
```